# verilog output gives x or 0 when using generate for and case

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm making adder array which has 4 32bit adders..

a0+b0 results in dout0, likewise a1,2,3 and b1,2,3.

But as you can see in image below, it d0, d1, d2, d3 always results in 0 or X.
How can I solve this problem?

```
module adder_array(
    cmd,
    ain0, ain1, ain2, ain3,
    bin0, bin1, bin2, bin3,
    dout0, dout1, dout2, dout3,
    overflow);

    input [2:0] cmd;
    input [31:0] ain0, ain1, ain2, ain3;    
    input [31:0] bin0, bin1, bin2, bin3;
    output reg [31:0] dout0, dout1, dout2, dout3;
    output [3:0] overflow;

    wire [31:0] a[3:0];
    wire [31:0] b[3:0];
    wire [31:0] d[3:0];
    wire ovf[3:0];
```

this is my 32bit add module used for adders

```
module my_add #(parameter BITWIDTH = 32)
(

    input [BITWIDTH-1:0] ain,
    input [BITWIDTH-1:0] bin,
    output [BITWIDTH-1:0] dout,
    output overflow
);

    assign {overflow, dout} = ain + bin;

endmodule


    assign {a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]} = {ain0,ain1,ain2,ain3};
    assign {b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]} = {bin0,bin1,bin2,bin3};
    assign {d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3]} = {dout0,dout1,dout2,dout3};
    assign overflow = {ovf[3], ovf[2], ovf[1], ovf[0]};

    parameter size = 4;


    genvar i;
    generate for(i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; i = i + 1)
     begin:adder
      if (i == 0) begin 
       my_add adder(.ain(a[0]), .bin(b[0]), .dout(d[0]), .overflow(ovf[0])); end
      else if (i == size - 1 ) begin
       my_add adder(.ain(a[i]), .bin(b[i]), .dout(d[i]), .overflow(ovf[i]));
      end
      else begin
       my_add adder(.ain(a[i]), .bin(b[i]), .dout(d[i]), .overflow(ovf[i]));
      end
     end
    endgenerate

always @(cmd) begin    

    case(cmd)

    3'b000 : begin dout0 = d[0]; dout1 = 0; dout2 = 0; dout3 = 0; end
    3'b001 : begin dout0 = 0; dout1 = d[1]; dout2 = 0; dout3 = 0; end
    3'b010 : begin dout0 = 0; dout1 = 0; dout2 = d[2]; dout3 = 0; end
    3'b011 : begin dout0 = 0; dout1 = 0; dout2 = 0; dout3 = d[3]; end
    3'b100 : begin dout0 = d[0]; dout1 = d[1]; dout2 = d[2]; dout3 = d[3]; end
    default : begin dout0 = 0; dout1 = 0; dout2 = 0; dout3 = 0; end
    endcase
    end

endmodule
```

it's my testbench module

```
module test_bench_32b_adder #(
    parameter BITWIDTH = 32
) ();

    reg [2:0] cmd;
    reg [31:0] ain0, ain1, ain2, ain3;
    reg [31:0] bin0, bin1, bin2, bin3;
    wire [31:0] dout0, dout1, dout2, dout3;
    wire [3:0] overflow;

    integer i;
    initial begin
        for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
            ain0 = $urandom%(2**31);
            ain1 = $urandom%(2**31);
            ain2 = $urandom%(2**31);
            ain3 = $urandom%(2**31);
            bin0 = $urandom%(2**31);
            bin1 = $urandom%(2**31);
            bin2 = $urandom%(2**31);
            bin3 = $urandom%(2**31);
            cmd = $urandom%(2**3);
            #10;
          end
        end

    adder_array  ADDER_ARRAY(
        .cmd(cmd),
        .ain0(ain0),
        .ain1(ain1),
        .ain2(ain2),
        .ain3(ain3),        
        .bin0(bin0),
        .bin1(bin1),
        .bin2(bin2),
        .bin3(bin3),
        .dout0(dout0),
        .dout1(dout1),
        .dout2(dout2),
        .dout3(dout3),
        .overflow(overflow)
        );
endmodule
```

Output of waves can be seen below,

[image]

Comment: your fragment #2 should not be compilable (32 add module). Can you provide a correct fragment or explain its contents? Did you put 'endmodule' in the wrong place? did you miss a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to cause the issue of 'X' which you have been observing, try removing this line

> `assign {d[0],d[1],d[2],d[3]} = {dout0,dout1,dout2,dout3};`

from your module.

Here by the above mentioned line you are trying to assign output to a wire which is having another driver which is from the my_add module, causing output to unknown "X" state,

This sums up like this `assign d[0]=dout` and `assign dout =d[0]` tries to assign values simultaneously resulting in 'X' on the bus.